# Simple Structs program in C

Tags: c, list, pointers, struct

I'm new to programming so please bear with me.  Can anyone please explain what the last line of code is doing and what this entire block of code trying to do. I know the first block is creating a structure called node and adding two pointers *next and *prev to it. btw this is a part of a linked list program

```
struct node
 {
  char line[80];
  struct node *next,*prev;
 };

struct node *start=NULL,*temp,*temp1,*temp2,*newnode;
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What C book are you using ? What does it say about pointers ?

Comment: Last line is similar to `struct node *next,*prev;` line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last line is creating 5 pointers of type `struct node` namely `start` which is pointing to `NULL`, `temp`, `temp1`, `temp2` and `newnode`.

The whole block of code is actually creating a struct called `node` which contains an array of 80 characters, followed by pointers to next and previous. Hence it is creating a structure for a doubly linked list.

Comment: Aniket that was exactly what i wanted to know..  thank you so much..  :)

Comment: I'm not sure whether 'creating' is the mot juste.  It defines a structure type called `struct node`, but there are no variables of the structure type created — there are only pointers to such types.

Answer (score 6):

```
struct node *start=NULL,*temp,*temp1,*temp2,*newnode;
```

can be as

```
struct node *start=NULL;
struct node  *temp;
struct node *temp1;
struct node *temp2;
struct node *newnode;
```

Now is it easy to understand..?

Answer (score 2):

The last line is creating 5 pointers of type struct node. Here start is initilaized to Null.

Answer (score 2):

The last line of code defines 5 variables, all of which are pointers to `struct node`.  One of them, `start`, is initialized to NULL; the others are also initialized to NULL if the variables are outside any function, but are uninitialized if they are inside a function.  Uninitialized pointers should be initialized before they are used.  Null pointers should not be dereferenced; madness lies at the end of a null pointer (or, more usually, a core dump).